# How can I send data from a child component to a child component without using props?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, vue.js, eventemitter

Is this possible And how to do this. I worked on a similar thing in vuejs like

```
this.$emit("send",payload)
```

and then listen in another component

```
this.$on("send",(payload) => {
/and do something the in another component
}
```

How to Do this in ReactJS

Comment: Why? That's what props are for.

Comment: You could dispatch a global event a'la Flux: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27473846/3430412

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is called *event bus* in vue.js, but it is an anti-pattern so it *was removed* from the API in *vue 3*.

However if you really liked that approach, you can probably achieve it with an *external library* that implements the *event emitter interface.*

You can read more about it here with provided example: https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/events-api.html#event-bus

Answer (score 4):

you can use a react context https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html
or redux https://redux.js.org/